# regex to remove alphanumeric from text

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the alphanumeric attached in front the text of words variable. I tried regex but not works.Please help.

```
words = c("A120 condition of returned veh","B520 vehivle of returned ve","petrol reserve switch")
```

```
Expected result = 
"condition of returned veh"
"vehivle of returned ve"
"petrol reserve switch"
```

Comment: "I tried regex but not works" Can you be more specific? What regex didn't work?

Comment: Just a doubt.  Suppose if you have numbers alone i.e. instead of `A120`, if it is `120`, would that be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match the pattern or zero or more digits (`\\d*`) followed by one or more alphabets and one or more digits as pattern and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\b\\d*[A-Za-z]+\\d+\\s*", '', words)
#[1] "condition of returned veh" "vehivle of returned ve"    "petrol reserve switch"
```

If we also need to remove numbers as well

```
gsub("\\b\\S*\\d+\\S*\\s", '', c(words, "120 condition of returned 35 veh"))
#[1] "condition of returned veh" "vehivle of returned ve"    "petrol reserve switch"     "condition of returned veh"
```